# groovy saving lines from file into collection

Tags: groovy

Hi I want do save collection from textfile in groovy and save only chosen lines.

I have a file contains that plaintext:

```
!!file-number1: 
!!123.sql
!!123.jpeg
!!333.jpeg 
!!texttextext.jpeg
```

and I want to save it to collection with that result
collection = ['123.jpeg', '333.jpeg', 333.jpeg', 'textextex.jpeg']
Only .jpeg and without "!!"

```
String filePath =  "path/to/file.txt"
File myFile = new File(filePath)

def collection = myFile.collect().retainAll {it == '*.jpeg'}
println collection
```

And my question is how to remove or ignore things like "!!" and how to print that collection, because i got only output "true".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `findResults` to "filter" and "map" in one go.  e.g.

```
def lines = """!!file-number1: 
!!123.sql
!!123.jpeg
!!333.jpeg 
!!texttextext.jpeg"""

println lines.readLines().findResults{ def m = it =~ /!!(.*\.jpeg)/; m ? m[0][1] : null }
// → [123.jpeg, 333.jpeg, texttextext.jpeg]
```

Comment: how can correctly add another *.sql or *.exe into ".findResults{ def m = it =~ /!!(.*\.jpeg)/; m ? m[0][1] : null }"

Answer (score 2):

Or a little bit easier to read, without using the Matcher object:

```
    String filePath =  "path/to/file.txt"
    def lines = new File(filePath)
        .collect()
        .findAll { it ==~ /.*jpeg/ }
        .collect { it[2..-1] }
    println lines
```

In your example, retainAll() modifies the initial collection and returns a boolean value. See here: https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html